# Slow update with ST_Contains()

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-performance

```
UPDATE tbl
SET city=s.city_name
FROM shp AS s
WHERE
ST_CONTAINS(s.city_geom,geom);
```

With the code above i can add exact city to a GPS point.
It runs about 45-50 min on 50 million rows.
There are about 4000 cities in the "city" table that have to be checked.

I have another shape file with 19 counties in a given country(only 1 country).
It takes it about 1,5 hour to add counties to points.

i have a third shape file with 52 EU countries.
It runs almost 25 hours with the same sql query.

Every table has index by geom, like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_txt_geom ON txt USING GIST(geom);
```

**Q**: Why is it so slow when it has to check only a few polygons ?

Explain Analyze:

```
Update  (cost=0.00..324.85 rows=1 width=286) (actual time=353.932..353.932 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=73090 read=1
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..324.85 rows=1 width=286) (actual time=0.544..341.936 rows=471 loops=1)
        Join Filter: _st_contains(s.geom, prob.geom)
        Buffers: shared hit=69985
        ->  Seq Scan on world s  (cost=0.00..83.44 rows=244 width=48) (actual time=0.009..0.319 rows=244 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=81
        ->  Index Scan using idx_prob_geom on prob  (cost=0.00..0.73 rows=1 width=270) (actual time=0.003..0.024 rows=9 loops=244)
              Index Cond: (s.geom && prob.geom)
              Buffers: shared hit=533
Total runtime: 354.640 ms
```

Comment: Add the `EXPLAIN` to show if it uses the indexes or not.

Comment: `explain (buffers, analyze)` please per [tag:postgresql-performance]

Comment: I made a Explain Analyze on a small datasample.

Answer (score 2):

ST_CONTAINS cannot use index.  Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET city=s.city_name
FROM shp AS s
WHERE
(geom && s.city_geom) and ST_CONTAINS(s.city_geom,geom);
```

`&&` checks bounding boxes and does use index.

Comment: Tried this on a small data sample as well, it didnt get faster.

Comment: It seems, ST_CONTAINS can use indices...
Try running VACUUM ANALYZE then.